# Build List of Lists from Delimited String in Powershell

Tags: powershell, loops

Very Simply put I am looking to take a string that is X length and parse it into an object.

The string will look like this: `0||1||2||3;a||b||c||d;10||11||12||13;`

My goal is to pipe that content into the following structure to be used as individual variables and values:

| var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| a | b | c | d |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |

My eventual goal is to be able to loop through these by calling a foreach loop (ie `foreach row in table: row.var1 + row.var2 +...etc`). The number of rows is not restricted, but the number of variables will always be 4 (I'll error handle if there are more or fewer).

I can obviously handle the initial part of converting the lines to rows:

`$rows = $Content -split ";"`

That returns this table:

| var |
| --- |
| `0||1||2||3` |
| `a||b||c||d` |
| `10||11||12||13` |

Then I parse through the rows and attempt to make cells (but this doesnt work the way I need it to):

```
table=@()
foreach ($row in $rows) {
    $cells = $row -split "\|\|"
    $table += ,$cells
}
```

Can anyone provide guidance or recommendations and what a loop might look like to kick me in the right direction?

I am seeing guides telling me to build things like this:

```
$NewRow=@{ 'var1' = "0" ; 'var2' = "1" ; 'var3' = "2"; 'var4' = "3"}
$table.Add($NewRow) | Out-Null
```

However, I am failing to think of a proper loop that would work to consistently fill those values or if that is the right approach.

*To clarify: I know this data format looks odd, but the possible data in the values can contain a ton of different delimiters, so || was by far the safest option given how I know how the data looks on a regular basis.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get my situation to work using the following formula:

```
$entries = @()   
foreach ($line in $inputLines) {
    $entryData = $line -split '\|\|'
    $obj = [PSCustomObject] @{
        var1  = $entryData[0]
        var2  = $entryData[1]
        var3  = $entryData[2]
        var4  = $entryData[3] 
    }  
    $entries += $obj
}
```

The other answers are super useful if the number of fields is unknown, but had issues outside the loop of keeping all content (likely from my usage). I found this to be the easiest method.

Answer (score 1):

For each row, construct a single object by collecting all the property values in a dictionary/hashtable, then cast to `[PSCustomObject]`:

```
'0||1||2||3;a||b||c||d;10||11||12||13;'.Split(';') |Where-Object {$_} |ForEach-Object {
  # create dictionary to hold property values
  $properties = [ordered]@{}

  # keep track of property number
  $varCount = 1

  # add each individual value to its own property entry in the dictionary
  $_ -split '\|\|' |ForEach-Object {
    $properties["var${varCount}"] = $_
    $varCount++
  }

  # cast and output resulting object
  [PSCustomObject]$properties
}
```

Comment: That works like charm! Thanks. I am extremely rusty with arrays so this was an amazing help.

Comment: It seems it has the output I needed, but it is only saving the last line of the loop rather than the entire object. Not sure if that was intended. If I call that object after I cannot see any other lines except the last one. I also cannot seem to add to the object at the end of the loop.

Comment: @TheGoblinPopper perhaps you'll want to collect the output to a variable? `$results = '0||1||2||3;a||b||c||d;10||11||12||13;'.Split(';') | ...`

Comment: I did that in the initial question. to break up rows into themselves, however, I am failing to loop through the rows to break it down and insert it as expected. I feel like the only major thing I need to fix with what you provided is where you wrote   ```# cast and output resulting object ``` I need to add that variable into the PSCustomObject before jumping to the next loop instances. Something like ```[PSCustomObject]$properties.Add($properties)``` because the loop outputs everything i want, I just want to put it all together into a variable.